# What's the purpose of the blooming process?

Tags: brewing-process, french-press, coffee-bloom

What exactly is the blooming process and why do we do it?

Excerpt from [Peets](http://www.peets.com/coffee/coffee-inside-the-cup/coffee-inside-the-cup-coffee-brewing/coffee-inside-the-cup-coffee-brewing-press-pot-brewing.html):

> Pour enough water to cover the grounds, start your timer and wait for
>   the grounds to puff up. This stage of extraction is called the
>   "bloom." Stir to saturate the grounds evenly. Then add remaining water
>   to fill. Fill to the top of the metal band.

Comment: See related questions: [what is coffee bloom?](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/337/what-is-coffee-bloom), which addresses what's happening and why. Another question specifically on [bloom and French press](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/does-the-bloom-matter-in-french-press). There's also a [tag:coffee-bloom] tag; I edited to add the tag. Is your question different from those?

Comment: I tried to use bloom as a tag but it didn't exist, why would 'bloom' need a 'coffee' prefix on a coffee forum? I'll read those posts, thank you

Comment: @hoc_age, yes they do, you can mark this as a duplicate

Comment: We asked the very same "coffee word in tag?" on [meta] at [here](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/80/can-tags-contain-the-word-coffee) and [here](http://meta.coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/77/retag-request-merge-drip-and-drip-coffee-completed)! By typing "bloom" in the tag part it *should* auto-complete... and you can search tags [here](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/tags). Okay, no problem -- I'll mark as dupe. Good question, though! Thanks.

Comment: And finally -- [this previous question about purpose of bloom](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21482/when-making-french-press-coffee-what-is-the-purpose-of-blooming-the-grounds) from [cooking.se]. :)