# Can I just put the coffee on top of the water in a French Press?

Tags: brewing-process, french-press

Related: [Does the bloom matter in French Press?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1683/does-the-bloom-matter-in-french-press)

The "proper" method, as I understand it:
(assuming proper grounds and tools)

1. Add coffee to empty press basin
2. Add 1-2 inches of boiling/hot water to initiate bloom for 30 seconds
3. Pour remainder of water to fill press basin (proportionate to amount of coffee used)
4. Set lid/plunger on top to preserve heat and wait for 4 minutes
5. Slowly plunger coffee, pour, and enjoy.

Because of my workplace configuration, this is somewhat inconvenient. It's easier and faster to pour the water first, and then put the coffee on top, making it instead look something like this:

1. Fill press basin with boiling/hot water
2. Scoop the appropriate amount of coffee on top
3. Set plunger on top, slightly pushing down the grounds, to preserve heat and wait for 4 minutes
4. Slowly plunger coffee, pour, and enjoy.

I have not noticed any appreciable difference in taste.

#### Does the coffee -> water -> water method really matter compared to my water -> coffee method

Note: I am using preground coffee (grinding at work is a mild inconvenience, and a potential HR concern ;] ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confession:
Many rules about making coffee are writen by perfectionists (or snobs or self-declared experts...) that are always on the hunt for the elusive *perfect* cup of coffee. So the general advice for making a certain type of coffee has to be taken with a grain of salt - which some people actually like to put in their coffee, btw.

To be honest, if you are using pre-ground beans anyway<sup>1</sup>, which is a compromise based on convenience already, and ***if you like your coffee***, I see no reason why you should not continue your current process. I personally might give the grounds a quick stir, just to make sure they are all wet and there are no dry lumps, before putting the lid on. If you are unhappy with what your method produces, I would suggest giving the “official” order a try or start tweaking the various parameters.

<sup>1</sup> There are affordable and good hand-cranked grinders available, just saying.

Comment: I had a little plastic burr grinder that quickly wore out. I plan on getting a metal burr on in the future.